# How to set a path with host in QUrl?

Tags: c++, qt, url

I am using QUrl to construct a string url. Let's say I need to get a "rtsp://camera.lan/stream" url.

The code below gives "rtsp://camera.lan" url:

```
QUrl url; 
url.setScheme("rtsp"); 
url.setHost("camera.lan"); 
auto url_str = url.toString().toStdString();  // "rtsp://camera.lan"
```

This one gives "rtsp:camera.lan" url:

```
url.setScheme("rtsp"); 
url.setPath("camera.lan"); 
auto url_str = url.toString().toStdString();  // "rtsp:camera.lan"
```

But if I set the path *with* the host it is not valid:

```
url.setScheme("rtsp"); 
url.setHost("camera.lan"); 
url.setPath("stream"); 
auto url_str = url.toString().toStdString();  // gives ""
bool url_is_valid = url.isValid();  // false
```

The [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#setPath) say,

> For non-hierarchical schemes, the path will be everything following the scheme declaration

But what if I need to specify the path *and* the authority?

Comment: Try to set path with `url.setPath("/stream");` instead. It will give you expected result: `rtsp://camera.lan/stream`.

Comment: @vahancho yes, it works. You may write it as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set path by calling `QUrl::setPath()` function like this:

```
url.setPath("/stream"); // Note the slash symbol.
```

instead. It will give you the expected result, i.e. `rtsp://camera.lan/stream`.